# My phonebook program doesn't sort my contact list correctly (ruby)?

Tags: ruby

I have this program with two classes: PhoneBook and PhoneContact. The goal of the program is to take a name with a phone number and the type of phone number it is (which is referred to as label). The PhoneContact class takes in a name and stores it as a contact. So, it works like this:

```
Bary_Bonds = PhoneContact.new(:work,'(111) 111-111', 'Barry Bonds')
```

The PhoneBook class takes in the phone contact and stores it in the directory. It can add, delete, find, and show all contacts in the phone book. I want to make a method that shows all the contacts in alphabet order.

This is my PhoneBook Class Code:

```
class PhoneBook
  attr_accessor :contact_list

  def initialize
    @contact_list = []
  end
```

This is my organize method:

```
 def organize
        puts @contact_list.each.map { |e| Array(e).join(", ") }.sort
      end
```

I'm not sure what to do here. I know that my code for the organize method only outputs the numbers and doesn't output the names of the contact. So, the above code returns this output:

```
(111) 111-1111
(222) 222-5222
(555) 555-5555
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As borbesaur mentioned, you need to sort by a name attribute on the PhoneContact objects. To customize the output, you'll need to implement a `to_s` method on PhoneContact:

```
class PhoneContact < Struct.new(:type, :number, :name)
  def to_s
    "#{name}, #{type}: #{number}"
  end 
end
```

You can use the method `sort_by` as a shortcut to sort your array of objects by an attribute:

```
  def organize
    puts @contact_list.sort_by(&:name)
  end
```

That should result in output like this:

```
Barry Bonds, work: (555) 555-5555
Bobby Bonilla, work: (222) 222-5222
Doug Drabek, work: (111) 111-1111
```

Comment: You can also write a comparator method and use the [`Comparable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Comparable.html) module to make them intrinsically sortable.

Comment: Does the `Struct.new` go in the PhoneContact class and not the PhoneBook class? I put in the PhoneContact class and then updated the orgainze method, but I still get this output: `(222) 222-5222
(555) 555-5555
(111) 111-1111`

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort it by name, rather than just sorting blindly.
First, you'll need an attribute accessor for your PhoneContact class on its name attribute. 
Something like this:

```
class PhoneContact
attr_accessor: name
def initialize(label, phone_number, name)
@name =name
end
```

Once you have that, just do this:

```
 def organize
    puts @contact_list.sort { |a,b|  a.name <=> b.name}
  end
```

Or if you want it to only output the names do this:

```
def organize
    puts @contact_list.sort { |a,b|  a.name <=> b.name}.map do |x|
      x.name
      end
  end
```

Comment: at the end of the PhoneContact class I did this: `alias number phone_number`. So, does doing `a.number work` and `b.number work`? Because it still gives the same output.

Comment: I misunderstood the question.  I've edited my answer.  This should work for sure.

Comment: The first way of the doing the organize method gives me this output:`(222) 222-5222
(555) 555-5555
(111) 111-1111
`  and the second way gives me this: `#<Enumerator:0x007fa3988ead30>`